# Match specific columns to another file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have two files below fileA and fileB. first three digits of column2 (fileA) will be matched from column1 (fileB). Column1 (fileA) must be equal to 63.

fileA

```
 63,918234
 64,918093
 63,920983
```

fileB

```
 918,XXX
 920,YYY
```

So far, I have this code that prints only the lines of fileA.

```
 awk -F~ 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1;next}{n=substr($2,1,3); sub(/^0+/, "", n); for(i in a)if(n~"^"a[i] && $1 ~"63")print $0}' fileB fileA
```

My expected output is

```
63,918234,XXX
63,920983,YYY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are getting tripped up by the fact that with a non-default field separator, `awk` does not remove leading whitespace? Possibly the easiest approach is to force the fields to be treated numerically:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR {a[$1+0]=$2;next} $1+0==63 {print $0","a[substr($2,1,3)+0]}' fileB fileA
 63,918234,XXX
 63,920983,YYY
```